# Form.Bounds with 2 screens

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have 2 screens, and 2 forms. I want each form to fill a screen, so I did the following code:

```
s = Screen.AllScreens
f1.Bounds = s(0).Bounds
f2.Bounds = s(1).Bounds
```

(s(0) is my primary screen, and s(1) is **above** it.) F1 fills s(0), but f2 does not fill s(1). The size of f2 is set correctly but the location is set to (50, 0) instead of (0, -1024). Maybe location won't accept negative numbers? If so, how can I get my form to the other screen?

**EDIT**

When you manually set the position of your form, you also have to set the `StartPosition` property to `Manual`, otherwise it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you able to set the value negative using `Location` or `Top` instead of `Bounds`?  Also, try overriding SetBoundsCore and seeing whether the value has been clipped yet at that point (may help narrow down where this is happening).

Comment: @Justin I can in the sense that I don't get any exceptions, but it's set to 0 instead of the negative value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your code for setting the bounds into the Form_load of each of the forms.  I was seeing the same thing you are and when I put the code into the Form_Load it worked as expected.

Comment: Thanks, that really worked. I still have the question, though, why doesn't this work if the bounds are set before Load?